# Как менять value input по кнопке +- если input text?

Tags: jquery

Есть у меня код, который вроде бы меняет значение input, но value как было первоначальным таким и остается.
Eще проблема если товаров несколько, то как цепляться за нужный input?

```html
<div class="numeric-input" data-title="Количество">
    <div class="quantity">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_63ce5ab7ed66e">Количество товара адсорбер ГАЗ-31105 дв.ЗИМ-405,УМЗ-4216,Крайслер</label>
        <input id="quantity_63ce5ab7ed66e"
               type="text"
               class="input-text qty text"
               name="cart[fb60d411a5c5b72b2e7d3527cfc84fd0][qty]"
               value="1"
               title="Кол-во"
               size="4" min="0" max="1" step="1"
               placeholder=""
               inputmode="numeric"
               autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
    <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
</div>
<script>
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("increase")) {
        ++e.target.parentElement.querySelector("input").value;
    } else if (e.target.classList.contains("decrease")) {
        --e.target.parentElement.querySelector("input").value;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: HTML-разметку Вы показали, а код-то где?

Comment: @XelaNimed извините, вот закинул

Comment: По факту значение изменяется, т.е. отображается в input поле правильно. При программном доступе, возвращается тоже правильное значение. Не понимаю в чём проблема того, что в значение аттрибута в инспекторе кода остаётся прежним? Если товаров несколько, то обычно в таких случая кнопки увеличения и уменьшения количества товара добавляются/дублируются для каждого товара отдельно (посмотрите ка это реализовано в корзинах любых интернет-магазинов).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема может быть в том, что вы изменяете значение свойства value элемента input, но не обновляете состояние формы, чтобы передать измененное значение на сервер. Для этого можно использовать событие change или input для элемента input, которое отслеживает изменения значения и обновляет состояние формы.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
       if (e.target.classList.contains("increase")) {
       let input = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("input");
       ++input.value;
       input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    } else if (e.target.classList.contains("decrease")) {
       let input = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("input");
       --input.value;
       input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
});
```

Для решения проблемы с множеством товаров, можно добавить класс к каждому элементу input и искать нужный используя этот класс. Или использовать идентификатор, который уникален для каждого товара.

Если вы используете jQuery, то можно использовать следующий код:

```
$('.increase').click(function(){
    let $input = $(this).parent().find("input");
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    $input.change();
});

$('.decrease').click(function(){
    let $input = $(this).parent().find("input");
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) - 1);
    $input.change();
});
```

В этом коде, мы используем событие `click` для кнопок увеличения и уменьшения, и метод `val` для изменения значения поля ввода. Метод `change()` отправляет событие change для поля ввода, так что форма может обновиться и отправить новое значение на сервер.

Comment: Ни первый ни второй код к сожалению не помог

Comment: Значит не правильно понимаю ваш вопрос

Comment: у меня не меняется value, но при этом в инпуте числа меняются а вот сам value как стоял 2 так и стоит 2, но приэтом если скажем кликнуть на инпут и ручками набрать, то все работает

Comment: тогда можешь так: `const value = parseInt($input.val()) - 1; $input.val(value).attr("value ",value)`

Comment: В самом инпуте value это атрибут, следовательно тебе надо менять еще и атрибут value